# How can i do this in Php get the LowByte

Tags: php

I need some help I am beginner of this kind of problem in php,.6A is the Low Byte of this

```
056A
```

But I want to know how it solved that 6A is the Low Byte.

I really don't have idea of this how to solve.I hope someone can help me or give me some idea to achieve this.

I appreciate some one will help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What data type is that supposed to be?

Comment: Please give more information things you tried !!!

Comment: Are you asking what a lower byte is, how to get the lower byte in php, or how to know which byte is lower vs highest (is how to get byte order) in php?

Comment: I think this kind of question "how to know which byte is lower vs highest" I am looking..My post is 6A is the lowbyte but I need to know how to come up with that answer to get 6A is the lowbyte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$low = dechex(0x056A & 0x00FF);
```

Comment: what is 0x00FF ? and why is that you prefix 0x to 056A ?

Comment: 0x is for hex numbers. The question didn't specify size of argument

Comment: dechex returns hex string

Comment: Hi,I think this is the answer I run the code and I get 6A,by the way can you please give me some references on this that talks about bytes etc...thank you

Comment: By the way can you please enlighten me on this "& 0x00FF".

Comment: 0x00FF is hex for 0000000011111111, & is binary AND operator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND